# Lagrange Mutiplier for inequality constraint

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

> I'm a bit confused about Lagrange multipliers. I know it works wonders if I only have equality constraints. Whenever I have inequality constraints, or both, I use Kuhn-Tucker conditions and it does the job.
>
> But my question is, can I solve a inequality constraint problem using only Lagrange multiplier?

*For example:*

min $f(x)=x^4$ with $x \leq -1$.

$L(x,\lambda)=x^4+ \lambda(x+1)$, gives:

$4x^3+ \lambda =0$ and $x+1=0 \Leftrightarrow x=-1 , \lambda =4$

Is this correct? I just assumed equality..  What happens if the constraint is not active?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Introducing the slack variable $\epsilon$ we can transform an inequality into an equality. So with this idea we can write the equivalent Lagrangian

$$
L(x,\lambda,\epsilon) = x^4+\lambda(x+1+\epsilon^2)
$$

The stationary points are solved by

$$
L_x = 4x^3+\lambda = 0\\
L_{\lambda} = x+1+\epsilon^2 = 0\\
L_{\epsilon} = 2\lambda\epsilon = 0
$$

Now, depending of the values for $\epsilon,\lambda$ we can qualify those stationary points.

NOTE

After solving we have the feasible solution $x = -1,\ \,\lambda = 4,\ \ \epsilon = 0$ which indicates that the restriction actuates.

Comment: I've seen this somewhere also. Is this the same as assuming that if constraint is active then $\lambda \geq 0$ and if its inactive we have $\lambda=0$? What I just said comes from what you did right?

Comment: forgot to tag you

Comment: @AmateurMathematician $\epsilon = 0$ indicates that the restriction is active. $\lambda > 0$ indicates that the objective function gradient $4 x^3$  points in the same direction as the restriction, at the solution point.

Comment: The stationary points are just the KKT conditions.

Comment: @Cesareo can tou recommend me a book on this 'slack variable'? Also why do the slack variable squared?

Comment: @AmateurMathematician Please have a look at  http://users.wpi.edu/~pwdavis/Courses/MA1024B10/1024_Lagrange_multipliers.pdf  and at  http://math.cmu.edu/~cnewstea/teaching/21-256/lagrange-multipliers.pdf